# command line utility for forking a gitlab repository

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to fork a gitlab repository through a command line script.
I am able to do this in the UI but I want to trigger a job in Jenkins which would fork the repository.

How can I achieve this?

I learnt hub (https://hub.github.com/) can be used for forking and tried it. Got the following error:

> hub fork --remote-name=origin
>       Aborted: could not find any git remote pointing to a GitHub repository

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please check the [help/on-topic] - Asking for external libraries is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please then [edit] your question, see [ask].

Comment: You can do it through Jenkins itself (no need to do it scriptly). It took me 10 seconds to google that. [check it](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example)

Comment: You can do things on top of a forked repo (which is done though UI even in your suggested link) through jenkins. But my question is how to fork a repo through Jenkins or command line

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zaquestion/lab offers a command for

```
lab fork
```

https://github.com/vishwanatharondekar/gitlab-cli seems to be the gitlab equivalent of 'hub'

but it seems, atm it can only create merge-requests but not fork.

https://github.com/clns/gitlab-cli and https://github.com/drewblessing/gitlab-cli also appear insufficient.

If you can code ruby, go or javascript, you can probably adapt one of these to also fork.